# Firebase email-verification with temporary password

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, email-verification

I have an React app where sport teams can sign up. 
A team has a coach, and that coach should be able to invite 
members of his team via e-mail.

I already setup the creating of team members by the coach through a form
where a temporary password is set

onSubmit of the form I call

```
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(data['email'],
      generateRandomPassword()) 
    .then(user => user.sendEmailVerification())
```

This is all well and working like a charm, but I cannot seem to figure out a hack that enables me to send the password with the email since the editing of the email template is greyed out in "Firebase Console".

Can anyone figure out a way to resolve this other than the coach informing each members of their respective password?

Comment: You shouldn't ever send the password (in plain text or otherwise) in an email

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd instead [send a password reset email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email), which contains a token that allows the recipient to reset the password. That means you can safely assume that a user who signs in has received this email and this verified their email address. So you can [use the Admin SDK to set their `emailVerified` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).

Comment: Of course! The answer was right under my nose :) Thanks!